# Multiple independent absolutely continous Random Variable

Tags: probability

> > [image: Question:]
> >
> > 1. Electric light bulbs made at a plant have exponentially distributed lifetime with parameter 2.   We take $1,000$ bulbs.   Estimate the probability that at least one light bulb has life time more than $\tfrac 32(1+\ln 10)$.

My thoughts so far and I get stuck:

[image: this]

> Lettuce be the lifetime of one light bulb that's more than $\tfrac 32(1+\ln 10)$.  $\quad X_k\sim{\exp(2)}$
>
> $\begin{align}\mathsf P( X_k > \tfrac 32(1+\ln 10)) & = \int_{\tfrac 32(I this)}^{\infty} 2 e^{-2t}\operatorname d t
> \\[1ex] & = \Big[-e^{-2t}\Big]_{\tfrac 32(1+\ln 10)}^{\infty}
> \\[1ex] &= e^{3(1+\ln 10)}
> \\[2ex] Y_K &\sim\mathcal{Binom}(1000, e^{3(1+\ln 10)})
> \end{align}$

Happy Thanksgiving and thanks in advance to those who helps!!

Comment: Please learn to post questions (especially ones this brief) and what you have tried instead of just linking to photos. There is a relationship between Poison and exponential distn's. Perhaps define the desired survival as as a Poisson event.

Comment: It did not take much work to type it out, except *reading* the second image was something of a challenge.  It's not nice to submit blurry photos of poor handwriting.  Please clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

You are well under way.

*Hint:* $\mathsf P(Y_k> 1) = 1-\mathsf P(Y_k=0)$